# Std AVD and GenyMotion behave differently

Tags: genymotion, android-virtual-device

An app developed using standard AVD via Eclipse works just fine.  I just installed GenyMotion and the app throws an NPE on a line that does not bother std AVD.  Difficult to believe that this would occur, but it does.  The code line gets a reference to a layout item using findViewById call.  Without providing any code could anyone offer any clues. Runs fine in AVD but raises an NPE using GM.

THIS ISSUE HAS BEEN RESOLVED - BY AUTHOR - PC RETURNED FROM 'SLEEP' AND NOW NO PROBLEM.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it.